# How to perform a lookup on an API via SSIS

Tags: json, rest, ssis

I need to perform a lookup in SSIS/SSDT much like the lookup task that is there, but the reference table is a JSON REST API.  I'm having issues understanding how to do this, and I cannot find any guidance on how to do this as most of the examples I have seen are REST data sources.

What I'm doing is using a column in a source table to be used as data to be submitted to a REST API, and then parse the JSON return to add columns in the throughput.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In a data flow, use a Script Component transformation to make a call to the API for each row.  A script component will allow you to add new columns to a new buffer and populate it with the data from the API.

Here is an example of using a script component:
http://salvoz.com/blog/2012/03/20/ssis-script-component-asynchronous-transformation/

Here is the ms documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136133.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

m

Comment: do you find that using a script slows down the throughput of the SSIS package?

Comment: and also, how do you make the API call in the script component? and parse the json?

Comment: Using a script is as fast as the service that you are calling.  I would parse the json by the examples that you found for c#.  This is a popular library you can use: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json